# Time window frame in Presto window function

Tags: database, presto

Let's say I have a table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_purchase (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id integer,
  purchased_item varchar (100),
  time timestamp
);
```

The purchased item consists of several category. I want to see how many ***unique purchased item per user_id*** for every 30 minutes. I'm thinking of counting the number of id by using window function, like code below

```
select user_id,
    count(id)
    OVER(PARTITION BY
    user_id,
    purchased_item
    order by time
    rows between time and time + interval '30' minute) AS total
    from tb_purchase
```

It works in PostgreSQL, but it doesn't seem to work in Presto. Is there any way to achieve the result I want?

Comment: Please clarify how the time boundary should be defined. One way to is to truncate to 30-minute boundaries (i.e., 00:00, 00:30, 01:00, ...). Another way is per-item boundaries. However, the question is where to start each time window. Suppose there is a purchase every 10 minutes. Or suppose there is a purchase at 00:15, 0:20, then at 01:00 and 01:25.

Comment: I already edit the detail of my question, I want the window start from current row + 30 minutes after per  user_id & purchased item.